# For a particular ID, check for every 3 mins and set a flag in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose I am having data as follows, The data has three columns ID, date and Time,

```
ID    date        Time
1   8/20/2016   20:27:25
1   8/20/2016   20:29:04
1   8/20/2016   20:29:05
1   8/20/2016   20:38:38
1   8/20/2016   20:38:38
2   8/20/2016   14:24:53
3   8/20/2016   21:18:37
3   8/20/2016   21:18:37
4   8/20/2016   01:08:34
4   8/20/2016   01:08:35
4   8/20/2016   01:08:35
4   8/20/2016   01:08:35
4   8/20/2016   11:08:35
4   8/20/2016   11:08:35
4   8/20/2016   11:08:35
5   8/20/2016   09:35:17
5   8/20/2016   09:36:05
5   8/20/2016   09:36:19
5   8/20/2016   09:36:21
5   8/20/2016   00:01:59
5   8/20/2016   00:04:59
6   8/20/2016   00:02:13
6   8/20/2016   00:02:17
6   8/20/2016   00:02:19
6   8/20/2016   00:02:21
6   8/20/2016   00:02:24
6   8/20/2016   00:02:26
6   8/20/2016   00:04:27
6   8/20/2016   00:04:27
6   8/20/2016   00:04:28
6   8/20/2016   00:04:30
6   8/20/2016   00:04:35
6   8/20/2016   01:45:23
7   8/20/2016   00:14:30
7   8/20/2016   00:14:33
7   8/20/2016   00:14:47
7   8/20/2016   00:14:56
7   8/20/2016   00:21:56
```

For every ID and particular date, I want to check the first time and then find out the entries corresponding to next 3 minutes and set a flag as 1. If the time is not within three 3 minutes, I want to set the flag to 2 and then keep checking for the next three minutes. Basically I want to find out three minute sets for every ID. I want to analyse the records for every three minutes and If there is a flag like this, It would help me in analyzing it.

the output I want is,

```
ID  date         Time     flag
1   8/20/2016   20:27:25    1
1   8/20/2016   20:29:04    1
1   8/20/2016   20:29:05    1
1   8/20/2016   20:38:38    2
1   8/20/2016   20:38:38    2
2   8/20/2016   14:24:53    1
3   8/20/2016   21:18:37    1
3   8/20/2016   21:18:37    1
4   8/20/2016   01:08:34    1
4   8/20/2016   01:08:35    1
4   8/20/2016   01:08:35    1
4   8/20/2016   01:08:35    1
4   8/20/2016   11:08:35    2
4   8/20/2016   11:08:35    2
4   8/20/2016   11:08:35    2
5   8/20/2016   09:35:17    1
5   8/20/2016   09:36:05    1
5   8/20/2016   09:36:19    1
5   8/20/2016   09:36:21    1
5   8/20/2016   00:01:59    2
5   8/20/2016   00:04:59    3
6   8/20/2016   00:02:13    1
6   8/20/2016   00:02:17    1
6   8/20/2016   00:02:19    1
6   8/20/2016   00:02:21    1
6   8/20/2016   00:02:24    1
6   8/20/2016   00:02:26    1
6   8/20/2016   00:04:27    2
6   8/20/2016   00:04:27    2
6   8/20/2016   00:04:28    2
6   8/20/2016   00:04:30    2
6   8/20/2016   00:04:35    2
6   8/20/2016   01:45:23    3
7   8/20/2016   00:14:30    1
7   8/20/2016   00:14:33    1
7   8/20/2016   00:14:47    1
7   8/20/2016   00:14:56    1
7   8/20/2016   00:21:56    2
```

where for every ID, date, for every 3 minutes, 1 is added to the flag.

I am not able to try regarding this as I am new to python. I apologize for this. If anybody can give any idea of how to do this, it would be helpful for me.

Comment: Your data set seems off to me: if I understand your logic, the first record with `8/20/2016   20:38:38` should be flagged as `1`, and the very previous record `8/20/2016   20:29:05` should have been flagged to `2`. Can you confirm and explain (or correct)?

Comment: @sal for a particular ID on a particular date, the flag should start with 1. it should be 1 until 3 minutes gets over. Once three minutes gets over, the flag should set to 2 and check for next 3 minutes. For every ID, every date, I would want to get 3 minutes set of values.

Comment: @zvone I tried with respect to two for loops for ID and date and then check for date - first value of date. But after that I am not able to complete it and also using two for loops makes the code very complex and time consuming.

Comment: Got ya. So you basically want to take a group of records based on (id, date) and then split that further in groups that represent 3 minutes of delta, starting from the first element in the group.

Comment: I see my question was too short. What I meant is you should post your code and say "i tried this thing here, but what it does is not what i expected. I expected A and I got B". Then someone can explain to you where you made a mistake. And you can learn. And others can learn from your example. If you post a question without code, you are basically asking for someone to implement the whole thing, which is not what SO is about.

Comment: @sal yes. for every three minutes, I would want the flag to increment

Comment: @zvone I am sorry. I am new to SO. I tried few and was not able to make out anything meaningful. So I thought it is better not to post what I did. I can sure update with what I tried. But what I thought was it could be misleading.

Comment: @gangi if the solution is the one you need, please mark it as `accepted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first to do would be to put the data in useful data structure: I chose a list of sets. These records would first need to be grouped by their (id, date) which is an easy task using the `groupby` function of `itertools`.

If the data came from a database, you could run such grouping in the database itself.

Then all that's left is to loop in each of those groups, and anytime the time delta between the initial record and the next exceeds 3 minutes (`3*60`) increase the `flag` value and update the `reference_time` so that it moves along.

Full code below, although data is reduced, but you can also see the whole working example at https://eval.in/636448

Note: I believe your reference data has an error in dataset `id=6`.

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime

data = [
('1', '8/20/2016', '20:27:25'),
 # ...
('7', '8/20/2016', '00:21:56')
]


FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
for key, group in groupby(data, lambda x: (x[0],x[1])):
    # group data based on (id, date), ignore 'key'

    reference_time = None
    flag = 1
    for cur_id, cur_date, cur_time in group:
        # for each group, test the delta-3 condition
        if reference_time is None:
            # init
            reference_time = cur_time
            print cur_id, cur_date, cur_time, flag
            continue
        delta = datetime.strptime(cur_time, FMT) - datetime.strptime(reference_time, FMT)
        if delta.seconds >= (3*60):
            # check if time diff is >= 3 minutes from start of sequence
            # increase flag, and update the reference timestamp
            reference_time = cur_time
            flag += 1
        print cur_id, cur_date, cur_time, flag
```

Result:

```
1 8/20/2016 20:27:25 1
1 8/20/2016 20:29:04 1
1 8/20/2016 20:29:05 1
1 8/20/2016 20:38:38 2
1 8/20/2016 20:38:38 2
2 8/20/2016 14:24:53 1
3 8/20/2016 21:18:37 1
3 8/20/2016 21:18:37 1
4 8/20/2016 01:08:34 1
4 8/20/2016 01:08:35 1
4 8/20/2016 01:08:35 1
4 8/20/2016 01:08:35 1
4 8/20/2016 11:08:35 2
4 8/20/2016 11:08:35 2
4 8/20/2016 11:08:35 2
5 8/20/2016 09:35:17 1
5 8/20/2016 09:36:05 1
5 8/20/2016 09:36:19 1
5 8/20/2016 09:36:21 1
5 8/20/2016 00:01:59 2
5 8/20/2016 00:04:59 3
6 8/20/2016 00:02:13 1
6 8/20/2016 00:02:17 1
6 8/20/2016 00:02:19 1
6 8/20/2016 00:02:21 1
6 8/20/2016 00:02:24 1
6 8/20/2016 00:02:26 1
6 8/20/2016 00:04:27 1
6 8/20/2016 00:04:27 1
6 8/20/2016 00:04:28 1
6 8/20/2016 00:04:30 1
6 8/20/2016 00:04:35 1
6 8/20/2016 01:45:23 2
7 8/20/2016 00:14:30 1
7 8/20/2016 00:14:33 1
7 8/20/2016 00:14:47 1
7 8/20/2016 00:14:56 1
7 8/20/2016 00:21:56 2
```

Comment: thank you.I have my data as dataframe. Can we use that directly and store the output as a column there?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that format, but I am sure you can.